# Conditional StreamFallback Data Source (DNN/2sxc)

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

Question moved from http://sexycontent.codeplex.com/discussions/654662#post1473430

Is it posible to make someting like StreamFallback Data Source, 
but that condition is not empty stream but some other flag/content value?

Or there is some other way to conditionaly baypass filter?

Sample diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now there is no data-source that can do this in the visual designer.

For such complex cases, please just use a bit of code. you can access all queries in code using

```
App.Data.Query["query name"]["stream name"]
```

so to get the list, you can do things like

```
var items = AsDynamic(App.Data.Query["AllTags"]["Default"]);
```

so a few if-statements + that should get you going

it's documented minimally here: http://2sxc.org/en/Docs-Manuals/Feature/feature/8744

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer better:
[Access additional DataPipeline from Razor view in 2sxc module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239330/access-additional-datapipeline-from-razor-view-in-2sxc-module)

Currently, the right syntax is:

```
App.Query["Query-Name"]["Stream-Name"];
```

and not:

```
App.Data.Query["Query-Name"]["Stream-Name"];
```

Comment: I don't know if App.Data.Query syntax is for old versions of 2sxc, but now work without Data part.
I use : dnn 8.00.02 and 2sxc 8.04.05

Comment: Actually the App.Data.Query is the right one :) but we "accidentally" published App.Query in a public interface, so we'll have to support it from now on :)

Comment: Is this mean that both ways are OK from now?