# Access additional DataPipeline from Razor view in 2sxc module

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

Is it posible to access another pipeline data from razor script 
already conected to custom or default data pipeline?

(multiple pipelines in one razor view)

eg: 
My custom data pipeline give me some values and base on this values I 
want to get some other custom pipeline and used its values/lists in conditional block 
of this razor script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list = App.Query["Query-Name"]["Stream-Name"].List;
foreach(var item in AsDynamic(list)){
    <div>@item.Title</div>
}
```

Also a good sample is:
[Using App Data Outside of 2sxc](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155356/using-app-data-outside-of-2sxc--in-razor-custom-webapi-skin-or-another-module-300)